# Kubuntu 18.04: I can't change my display resolution

Tags: kubuntu, display-resolution

I just installed Kubuntu 18.04.

And for some reason I'm stuck on 1024x768 but my monitor is 1400x900.

I can't change it in the settings.
When I try to use Xrandr I get

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Xrandr says the maximum is 1024x768.

Is this a plasma thing? What do?

Comment: What's the max resolution of the display adapter in your PC? If you tell us the make of the PC and the Hardware Model Number from the serial number sticker, we can look that up. Also, do `sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'` to find what driver you are using. Click [edit] to put that highly useful info into your question so all may see it; please don't use Add Comment.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about an external monitor, there's a good chance that your video cable needs to be replaced. If we're talking about a laptop display (or other display), there's a good chance that you need to install the proper video driver ie: Nvidia, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my 18.04 computer with me this second, but under [Settings](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/systemsettings/using-kapp.html) -> Display (I think) there should be a resolution option.  There is certainly a kde menu for resolution somewhere under settings.

Comment: There is but it only has the 1024x768 resolution option.

Comment: what is the max res your monitor can take?  its make?